Failed to restart sshd.service: Unit sshd.service not found
This is on ubuntu.-I edited Password to yes on my sshd_config file in my /etc/ssh directory. having done this i tried to restart the deamon using sudo systemctl restart sshd and i keep getting this error "Failed to restart sshd.service: Unit sshd.service not found". what can i do to restart it

Have you tried sudo systemctl restart ssh? that's the actual unit name (sshd is an alias - see for example journalctl -u sshd.service command returns 'no entries'

This question is similar to: Failed to restart sshd.service. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ubuntu 22.10 and newer don't run an always-on sshd listener anymore.
Restarting sshd to load a changed config is no longer needed on these newer releases.
Now systemd does the listening. When an inbound connection attempt is detected, systemd starts sshd, which then freshly loads the sshd config.
After you have saved your sshd_config file, all subsequent connections will use the new config.
See https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sshd-now-uses-socket-based-activation-ubuntu-22-10-and-later/30189

Valuable info, but probably should point out the OP entered a wrong command.

@OrganicMarble it shouldn't actually be "wrong" though - unless the OP has somehow deleted the /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service symlink
